# Building Hierarchies for Business Areas in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am combining communications from multiple projects that differ in granularity, but need to see them combined. For example, I have some communications that go to everyone within the Enterprise, while others that will go to just IT, and then some to just the IT Leader. Currently, if I click on the IT Leader, it will only display the communications directly to this individual, but in reality they are also receiving the Enterprise-wide and IT-wide communications as well.

I tried creating hierarchies in my data and expanding them to create duplicate rows for the same communication (e.g. one communication going out to all of IT would have two rows of data associated with it tagged to both IT & IT - Leader) but I am running into issues where I am seeing too much data show up.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Examples: (Click on RED and anything that goes to GREY should show in the dashboard)

[image]

Comment: I couldn't understand exactly what you're asking for, but maybe [this article](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2019/10/03/parent-child-hierarchies-with-multiple-parents-in-power-bi-with-power-query/) from Imke may give you some hints

Comment: That's something close to what I'm looking for... What I'm trying to do is create a calendar visual that shows any communication that is going to hit a specific group (e.g. IT - Leader).  As of today, this calendar shows me anything that explicitly calls out IT - Leader, but it doesn't show any communications that are marked to go to all of IT or all employees.  I'm looking for the wholistic view

Answer (score 1):

I may suggest 3 options. Each has pros and cons.

### Option 1: "Extended Recipient" factless fact table

Create a table with every combination of direct and extended recipients.

[Extended Recipient table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07nMt.png)

For example, people in "IT - LEADER" should have received messages directly bound for "IT - LEADER", "ITLT", and "IT - All Employees", so "IT - LEADER" is repeated 3 times with each of these direct recipient group.

Then you should create relationships as below. Notice that the relationship between Direct Recipient and Extended Recipient has "Both" direction.

[image: Schema]

Now you can filter the communications based on Extended Recipient. For simplicity, I have only 4 communications in my sample dataset. Below image shows it is successfully filtering the communications for different selections of Extended Recipient slicer.

[image: Result 1]

#### Pros:

**It saves storage consumption**. It might be looking redundant to save all combinations of ancestors and descendants in the hierarchy. However, it goes up to only some tens of thousands of rows even if the organization hierarchy is as deep as 100 levels, which is very unlikely.

#### Cons:

It uses a **both direction relationship**, which is in general something you would want to avoid as much as possible.

### Option 2: "Communication Recipient" fact table.

You may choose to hold a factless fact table with communications along with all extended recipients.

For example, communication #1 was bound for "IT - All Employees", so Communication Recipients will have 6 rows corresponding to every group in the organization.

[Communication Recipient table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeNgD.png)

The schema will be a basic star schema with two dimension tables, one for unique communications which may have a column to hold the direct recipients, and one for extended recipients.

[image: Schema 2]

#### Pros:

It is a perfect **star schema**!

#### Cons:

It may considerably increase **storage space**, because it is multiplying the fact table rows. If you have more than tens of millions of communications, this may not be acceptable.

### Option 3: Many-to-many relationship

This option is just a variant of Option 1. You may use many-to-many relationship in "Both" cross filter direction to connect Communication table and Extended Recipients table directly. In this case you don't need Direct Recipient table.

[image: Schema 3]

Pros and cons are almost the same as Option 1. It looks even concise, but you need to take greater caution on the potential danger with many-to-many relationship in both direction mode.